# BatchFile about using if exist

Tags: batch-file

I am making batch files for about half a year now, but I never got this problem ever, and nothing that i use works, i am on windows 10 x64 bit if that changes something. This is the following scripts:

```
@echo off    
title The Battling Simulator [TBS] - Nickname Selection    
cls    
:name    
cls    
if exist "%name%" (    
goto welcomeback    
) else (    
goto createname    
)    
:welcomeback    
echo fire server    
pause    
:createname    
set /p name=Name :    
echo name created    
echo test > %name%    
pause
```

The problem is, as you look in the batchfile script, i want the program to check if you already have introduced the name once, so it remembers the name permanently by creating a file, so if i were to name myself "Axel", it will create a file on my desktop called "Axel", and if the file already exist it should go to the section "welcomeback", but it just doesn't do that, it just goes to createname section.
If the name isn't already introduced and you are new to the program, then it will ask you for your name, after that it's gonna create a file of your name and remember it on your desktop, then you are gonna try to re-enter the program and it should make you go to the category welcomeback.

More shorter, it ignores the category ":welcomeback" and it only goes to ":createname" by checking if a file of your name is already created. I really need help cuz his never happened to me.

Sincerly,
Mike.

Comment: At this time, there are two tags: bash and batch-file.  I suggest "bash" be removed.  (Since I just submitted an answer, I'm hesitant to also adjust the question.)

Comment: @TOOGAM I removed the `bash` tag.

Comment: what did you try to troubleshoot it?

Comment: quick answer is with labels if you want it to exit after you need `goto :end`

Comment: `"I am making batch files for about half a year now..." `  Why??? If you're on Windows 10, you should be learning PowerShell. More powerful, easier to code/read. There's a reason PowerShell is the default console app on the WinX menu.

Answer (score 0):

The `:name` label has no effect.  (The label doesn't get used at all.)  If you want a label to be a comment, the command interpreter actually goes a bit faster if you have a second colon.  (e.g., `::name`)  That is the fastest way to comment something (even faster than the `REM` command), and makes it clear to people that the label is not something that you try to `GOTO` at any point.  (You cannot `GOTO` a label that starts with an additional colon, coming immediately after the first mandatory colon.)

If a file with a filename of `%name%` exists, then what this will appear to do is to go to `:welcomeback`

Then, after the `:welcomeback` label, the batch file should `echo fileserver`, and then go to the next line.

Then, it should pause.

Then, the batch file should proceed to the next line, which is the `:createname` label, which has no effect (except when the batch file is looking for that label in order to go to it).

Then, the batch file proceeds to the next line, which prompts for the name.
`set /p name=Name :`

Try this:

```
@echo off
title The Battling Simulator [TBS] - Nickname Selection
cls

if exist "%NAME%" GOTO welcomeback
GOTO createname

:welcomeback
:: Got here because %name% existed.
echo fire server
pause
goto end

:createname
set /p NAME=Enter your name :
echo name created (%NAME%)
echo test > %NAME%
pause
:: (Next, falls through to the :end label)

:end
```

Comment: 1) If swap `:welcomeback` and `:createname` codeblocks then the line `GOTO createname` is excess and may be deleted. 2) For to jump to the end of batch use `goto :EOF` instead of `goto end`, and you do not need to define any (`:end` in this particular case) label.

Comment: 3) The file which name is equal to `%NAME%` variable is searched in current drive/folder. It is safe to use explicit `cd /d` command or `pushd` instruction for to set correct current drive/folder. 4) User may insert a name with a symbol(s) which will cause incorrect statement while inserting instead `%NAME%`. For example, `|` or `<` or `&&`... No way to check with guarantee. 5) Entered name may contain space(s) or similar symbol(s) which needs to quote this value while using it as a filename.

Comment: @Akina: We clearly have different coding styles/goals. 1) Your proposed approach is optimized for more performance, but I think changing the order decreases simplicity, reducing readability/understandability. This answer is designed for clear communication (showing how something works), not optimizing for speed or step minimization. Using the same order as the original question just felt clearer (for an inexperienced reader). 2) I try to utilize standards that work with more operating systems. Besides "title" and "set /p", little here needs newer functionality found in fewer operating systems.

Comment: 3) Avoided for the same reason as 2. Besides, nothing in the question indicates this is a concern that isn't addressed (elsewhere). 4) Defending against such attacks/errors adds to complexity, desirable for professional software, but less appropriate for an answer which is meant to be simple and direct/to-the-point. 5) Fair enough (in the "echo test" line), but this was just a copy-paste from the question, and isn't necessarily breaking what the question asks about. You clearly have some coding know-how, but such good higher standards just weren't what this answer focused to accomplish.

Comment: *We clearly have different coding styles/goals* Maybe. And I don't see anything wrong with that. *work with more operating systems* OP defines directly: "windows 10 x64 bit". *against such attacks/errors* .. misprintings.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't demonstrate name being defined as a variable.
The method For Doing this would Be to Create a Directory for Users, and Store users as name.txt, name.sav or, if your saving user information, name.bat files.

I recommend using bat files in any instance where you want to recover information, as you can store information in it in a way that allows you to CALL that file to reassign any variables that user needs.

This approach easily facilitates multiple Users, by doing as follows

```
@ECHO OFF

::: The below line assigns the Directory path your Program is in to the variable
::: for later use

Set Program_DIR=%~dp0

::: This creates the Directory for your User files

IF NOT EXIST "%Program_DIR%\Users" MD "%Program_DIR%\Users"

:login
cls
ECHO Welcome!
Set /p name=[Enter your Username to continue:]

IF not defined name GOTO login
IF Exist "%Program_DIR%\Users\%name%.bat" (
CALL "%Program_DIR%\Users\%name%.bat"
    ) else (
    GOTO New_User
)

:programMENU

::: Your program

:New_User

::: Save the users Name, and Assign the file to Variable to CALL when you wish to
::: store/Retrieve.

ECHO 0>"%Program_DIR%\Users\%name%.bat"
Set "LoadSave=%Program_DIR%\Users\%name%.bat"
```

Using paths relative to the folder your program is in will ensure no broken links if the folder is moved, and eliminates any guesswork regarding what directory path it's at.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include an `:end` at the end, and a `goto :end` at the end of your "welcome" section so it doesn't continue through. So I just added those two lines to your program.

```
@echo off    
title The Battling Simulator [TBS] - Nickname Selection    
cls    
:name    
cls    
if exist "%name%" (    
goto welcomeback    
) else (    
goto createname    
)    
:welcomeback    
echo fire server    
pause    
goto :end
:createname    
set /p name=Name :    
echo name created    
echo test > %name%    
pause
:end
```

It's a standard design pattern with GOTO in batch e.g. mentioned here https://www.robvanderwoude.com/goto.php  see the design of each label having some code and ending in a `goto End`.  It's a good usage of goto, very clear.

There are also other things people may do with GOTOs e.g. to get the effect of iteration(not really done nowadays), or to get the effect of subroutines(also not done much nowadays, there's the 'call' keyword which is better for making a subroutine effect, which does a goto and returns to where it was called from.

Maybe you never ran into the issue you are running into in the past because in the past you often had a label in the end that you'd GOTO, and no label after it.

Also, as one answer has mentioned, you aren't using `:name` i.e. you aren't doing a GOTO on it, so you may as well remove that label.